# How to implement reflection with enum type of argument in target function

Tags: vb.net

Here is a test code:

```
Public Class Class2
   Public GoodName as String
   Public Function someFunction ()
   End Function
End Class

Public Class Class1
    Public Enum ENUM_VAL1_
       abc = 1
       def = 2
    End Enum

    Public Enum ERROR_VAL1_
       yhn = 1
       ujm = 2
    End Enum

    Public Function fun1(byval _enumArg1 as ENUM_VAL1_,
                         byval _stringArg as String,
                         byref _classArg Class2) as ERROR_VAL1_
       ... SOMETHING HERE
       return something
    End Function
End Class
```

AND THE TEST

```
    Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(<the source>)
    If asm Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

    Dim typ As Type = asm.GetType(<namespace>.<class1>)
    If typ Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

    Dim obj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(typ)
    If obj Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

    Dim arg As Object() = New Object() {ENUM_VAL1_.abc, "qazxsw", New Class2}

    Dim res As Object = typ.InvokeMember( _
        "fun1", _
        BindingFlags.[Default] Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, _
        Nothing, _
        obj, _
        arg)
```

The [`Dim res As Object = typ.InvokeMember( _
        "fun1", _
        BindingFlags.[Default] Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, _
        Nothing, _
        obj, _
        arg)`]
return an error: `function '[fullname]' not found.`

Then I realize that fun1 signature is different from my call (even though enum values are integers). I did some research and I found "some" samples on how to implement reflection when property or function on target assembly have arguments different than standard types. But I was successful on translating those samples "concepts" to my need.

So, here I put some dummy classes with dummy enum types just to point out the skeleton of the problem.

The original code is about windows firewall/ports (win7/xp/vista) where there are many enumerated values including types from firewallApi.dll and Hnetcfg.dll.

The problem I have is that I cannot "InvokeMember" (also "SetProperties" and "SetProperties") using say:

```
Dim args As Object() = New Object() {"SQL", 6, "1433", 1}
```

where my function from assembly has these argument types.

```
Public Function PortExists( _
    ByVal _ruleName As String, _
    ByVal _protocol As NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_, _
    ByVal _remotePorts As String, _
    ByVal _direction As NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_ _
) As FW_ERROR_CODE
```

ok, to simplify I made my own enum types (no additional library needed to be installed)

```
Public Function PortExists( _
    ByVal _ruleName As String, _
    ByVal _protocol As FW_IP_PROTOCOL, _
    ByVal _remotePorts As String, _
    ByVal _direction As FW_RULE_DIRECTION _
) As FW_ERROR_CODE
```

somehow argument '6' and '1' should be converted to `FW_IP_PROTOCOL` and `FW_RULE_DIRECTION` types respectively...

I don't know how!

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve and why it is not working. What happens? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the solution.

When we use an Invoke method from the reflection, we must pass arguments as objects (object ()) with exact match of types.
Even though the value of enum type is an integer (this is where I had my original problem), I had to convert this value to the exact enum type of the reference assembly type. So the following function <_FEnumToObject> will do this job. I added _F to push all my private functions bottom of the list and group them (IDE property list); _S will stand for subs and _P for properties...

```
Private Function _FEnumToObject( _
    ByVal _typeName As String, _
    ByVal _typeValue As String _
) As Object
    Dim enumType As Type = m_Assembly.[GetType](_typeName)
    Dim enumInfo As FieldInfo = enumType.GetField(_typeValue)
    Dim valueINT As Integer = CInt(enumInfo.GetValue(enumType))
    Dim valueOBJ As Object = [Enum].ToObject(enumType, valueINT)
    Return valueOBJ
End Function
```

This next function <_FProtocolToObject> is for converting protocol value (enumurated) to an object.

```
Public Function _FProtocolToObject(ByVal _protocol As FW_IP_PROTOCOL) As Object
    'where <m_AssemblyRef> is like "wf7."
    Return _FEnumToObject(m_AssemblyRef + "FW_IP_PROTOCOL", _protocol.ToString)
End Function
```

And here is the final call:

```
Public Function PortExists( _
    ByVal _ruleName As String, _
    ByVal _protocol As FW_IP_PROTOCOL, _
    ByVal _portNumber As Integer _
) As Boolean
    If m_AssemblyNotFound Then Return False
    Static mi As MethodInfo = m_RemoteType.GetMethod("PortExists")
    Dim m As FW_ERROR_CODE = FW_ERROR_CODE.UNKNOWN
    Try
        Dim a As Object = New Object() _
            { _
                _ruleName, _
                _FProtocolToObject(_protocol), _
                _portNumber _
            }
        m = mi.Invoke(m_RemoteObject, a)

    Catch ex As Exception
        'some error handler here...

    End Try
    Return (m = FW_ERROR_CODE.SUCCESS)
End Function
```

I'm posting also few extra codes to present some unexplained/unset variables assignments in my sample codes.

```
Private ReadOnly Property _PAssemblyPath() As String
    Get
        Dim ad As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "bin")
        Dim af As String = IO.Path.Combine(ad, _PAssemblyName + ".dll")
        Return af
    End Get
End Property
```

Public Sub New()

```
    m_AssemblyPath = _PAssemblyPath
    m_AssemblyRef = _PAssemblyName + "."
    m_ClassPath = m_AssemblyRef + _PClassName

    If IO.File.Exists(m_AssemblyPath) Then

        Dim name As New AssemblyName()
        name.CodeBase = m_AssemblyPath
        m_Assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(name)
        m_RemoteObject = m_Assembly.CreateInstance(m_ClassPath)
        m_RemoteType = m_Assembly.[GetType](m_ClassPath)
        m_AssemblyNotFound = False

    Else
        'some error handler here

    End If

End Sub
```

Just assume that the 'SCSysInfo' is a utility class to check the OS system etc...

```
Private ReadOnly Property _PClassName() As String
    Get
        Dim s As String = "CFwRule"
        If SCSysInfo.IsWin7 Then
            s += "7"
        ElseIf SCSysInfo.IsWinVista Then
            s += "Vista"
        ElseIf SCSysInfo.IsWinXP Then
            s += "XP"
        End If
        Return s
    End Get
End Property
Private ReadOnly Property _PAssemblyName() As String
    Get
        Dim s As String = String.Empty
        If SCSysInfo.IsWin7 Then
            s = "fw7"
        ElseIf SCSysInfo.IsWinVista Then
            s = "fwv"
        ElseIf SCSysInfo.IsWinXP Then
            s = "fwxp"
        End If
        Return s
    End Get
End Property
```

'PortExists' function in my class (partially listed above) has two more signatures for vista and win7. One thing I must mention that reflection does not recognize method/property multiple signatures. When use reflection you must have only one signature for a method or for a property. Talking about my case: win7, vista and xp expose completely different properties for ports to program. In each assembly (that I compiled in respective environments), there are "identical" methods and properties with different number of arguments. From my "adapter" class (part of which is posted above) I call the "same" method from all 3 assemblies with 3 different signatures (based on OS I choose appropriate signature). So, my all 3 signatures for "PortExists" method are in my "adapter" class. I hope my explanation makes sense...Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Often a good design makes Reflection superfluous. My suggestion is to let different objects implement some common interface defining the function to be called.

Common definitions:

```
Public Enum MyValueEnum
    value1 = 1
    value2 = 2
End Enum

Public Enum MyErrorEnum
    error1 = 1
    error2 = 2
End Enum

Public Class SomeClass
    Public GoodName As String

    Public Function SomeFunction() As Object
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

The interface

```
Public Interface IMyInterface
    Function TheFunction(ByVal val As MyValueEnum, ByVal name As String, _
                         ByRef someObject As SomeClass) As MyErrorEnum
End Interface
```

Two different classes implementing the interface

```
Public Class SomeImplementation
  Implements IMyInterface

  Public Function TheFunction(ByVal val As MyValueEnum, ByVal name As String, _
                              ByRef someObject As SomeClass) As MyErrorEnum _
      Implements IMyInterface.TheFunction
      '...
      Return MyErrorEnum.error1
  End Function
End Class

Public Class SomeOtherImplementation
  Implements IMyInterface

  Public Function TheFunction(ByVal val As MyValueEnum, ByVal name As String, _
                              ByRef someObject As SomeClass) As MyErrorEnum _
      Implements IMyInterface.TheFunction
      '...
      Return MyErrorEnum.error2
  End Function
End Class
```

The test

```
Dim obj As IMyInterface
Dim result As MyErrorEnum

obj = New SomeImplementation()
result = obj.TheFunction(MyValueEnum.value1, "test", New SomeClass())

obj = New SomeOtherImplementation()
result = obj.TheFunction(MyValueEnum.value2, "another test", New SomeClass())
```

Comment: The <<Dim res As Object = typ.InvokeMember( _
        "fun1", _
        BindingFlags.[Default] Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, _
        Nothing, _
        obj, _
        arg)>>
return an error: function '<fullname>' not found.

Then I realize that fun1 signature is different from my the reflection (even though enum values are integers). I did some research and I found "some" samples on how to implement reflection when property or function on target assembly have arguments different than standard types. But I was successful on translating those samples "concepts" to my need.

Comment: I think I mislead you with "implement" expression. My problem is reflection, where target function/property has enum or object type of arguments. Sorry for that...

Comment: enums are really just integers, so it should be fine to just pass integers instead, when using reflection.

Comment: I am still not sure why you are using reflection. Just because the function is in an external dll (COM or .NET) is not a reason.

Comment: The reason I'm using reflection i that on win7, vista and xp firewall.dll (so Hnetcfg.dll) interfaces with different properties and methods. So, I have to compile each windows version in their own environment then call from my application. Within my application I can check the version of windows and call appropriate assembly. I've tried hard to make one single dll for all versions but it didn't work. so, i have no other choice but to use reflection...

Comment: I guess I couldn't explain my problem well...:(

Comment: Couldn't you make wrappers for each of the two components that expose the same methods and properties and that implement the same interface?